# color code editor for sass scss windows

Tags: sass

I am looking for the simple color code software to edit scss file for windows. 
I am sorry if the question is repeated but i am tired of searching and found mostly broken files. 
Please Suggest

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm making the assumption that you are asking for a windows text-editor that supports SCSS syntax highlighting, and not a color-picking utility.

If so, I would recommend 
[notepad++](http://notepad-plus-plus.org/) with user defined SCSS hightlighting [EDIT - old link broke, swapping out for new one] that you can download [here](http://blog.marvinlabs.com/2012/08/03/scss-syntax-highlighting-for-notepad/) or another [here](http://s3.amazonaws.com/files.posterous.com/temp-2011-01-10/zBrpwzDJrrbCIdzhJGinqxyxpneBnnGamgBpayzqvryCwaowhwBnjEJdtgkn/userDefineLang_SCSS.xml?AWSAccessKeyId=AKIAJFZAE65UYRT34AOQ&Expires=1353075617&Signature=0hXhZ8abe9eFtfRpjdVMEAFovA8%3D)

or, if you are willing to pay $60, [Sublime Text 2](http://www.sublimetext.com/2) is the best windows/mac/linux text editor (IMHO). There is a [SCSS Plugin](http://tech.wiedo.nl/sass-3-notepad-user-defined-syntax-highlighti) that should have everything you need.

If that is not what you are looking for, please clarify your question so we can help you better.

Comment: Hi, thanks for replying. I am sorry for my unclear post. I was searching for the color code text editor for scss. Currently am using notepad++ to edit scss file but its without any color. It would be better if i could use it for free.

Comment: I updated the question above with a link to a notepad++ syntax highlighting file. Here's the [link](http://blog.marvinlabs.com/2012/08/03/scss-syntax-highlighting-for-notepad/) again just in case.